# Pug 2 - Pushing Array in Loop

Tags: arrays, loops, variables, pug

I'm creating a document that will help me reduce time down when creating templates. I'm wanting to loop around a block of code in a seperate file with an array that I've specified in the header of the main file but can't seem to get it to work

**./src/pug/layout.pug**

```
- const flyouts = []
- flyouts.push({variationid: "123", plugin: "none", zone: "ZoneHere", variation: "LargeImage", link: "www.bbc.co.uk", imgloc: "blah.jpg"});
- flyouts.push({variationid: "456", plugin: "none", zone: "ZoneHere", variation: "LargeImage", link: "www.bbc.co.uk", imgloc: "blah.jpg"});
```

Calling the Loop here, in the same file

```
html
    head
        title Hello asd
    body 
        section
            // Flyouts
            each myFlyout in flyouts 
                include components/flyouts
```

Which calls this block of code in **./src/pug/components/flyouts.pug**

```
 .section(variationid=variationid plugin=plugin zone=zone variation=variation)
    a(href='asd')
        img(src='http' alt="Event" width="206" height="148" border="0")
```

Anybody able to shine a light on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jade/Pug keeps the variable scope of the parent template, while including a template. Variable you are looking for here is myFlyout, which is an object with other values - variationid, plugin, etc.

You need to use myFlyout to get values within flyouts.pug. This should work -

```
.section(variationid=myFlyout.variationid plugin=myFlyout.plugin zone=myFlyout.zone variation=myFlyout.variation)
  a(href='asd')
    img(src='http' alt="Event" width="206" height="148" border="0")
```